# Xamarin 4.8.0 System.Net.WebRequest.CachePolicy Mocking a setter

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Up till this morning I was using the latest non beta Xamarin.Android (4.6.8). This had support for setting System.Net.WebRequest.CachePolicy which is used in a 3rd party library I reference in a project. I don't have the source code for this library and so cannot remove the line or replace it with HttpClient and the library is fundamental to the project.

Hopefully Xamarin will reinstate support for this property but if they don't, I'd like to know how to mock/dummy/extend/replace the property to make the code compile. No functionality is required behind this property.

Can this be done? Is this approach even correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you take this problem direct to support@xamarin.com

It sounds like a breaking change in a brand new commercial software update - so I suspect it's something that the commercial support can help with more easily than the community.

Comment: Thank you. You're right and I had contacted them. I should have been specific that this was a question about workarounds to get the code to compile in the mean time. Instead I've just installed old Xamarin. Loving MvvmCross by the way!

Comment: thanks - I'd normally add this sort of thing as a comment rather than an answer - but was on mobile and answering was less taps :)